# element positioning in css3

Tags: html, css, web, sass

Its one of my project for a navigation design. When I stretch a window, those rotated div gets
scattered .Can someone suggest me what can I do in this case, I want it to be always at same
place when resizing/zooming a window. Thank you for help.
The result in the large screen is what the original placment of those divs should look but when I resize to smaller one, those divs get overlap on each other

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main_div{
    height:100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    
    
}

.div1{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    left:5%;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
   
}

.div2{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background:red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 14%;
    left:9%;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    

    
}

.div3{
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
    background:white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 33%;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    left:1%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    
    
    
}

.div4{
  height:90px;
  width: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  top:43%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left:7%;
  margin-left:0.7%;
}

.div5{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background:yellow;
    position: absolute;
    top: 53%;
    left:13%;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="nav.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main_div">
            <div class="div1"></div>
            <div class="div2"></div>
            <div class="div3"></div>
            <div class="div4"></div>
            <div class="div5"></div>
            <div class="div6"></div>
            <div class="div7"></div>

        </div>
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->
        
        <script src="" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you don't want the elements to be effected by window dimension, use fixed pixel values instead of percentages.

Answer (score 0):

I would say position it relatively, for you don't want the divs to overlap. Instead of absolute position use relative position for divs, and position it accordingly. Example:

`position: relative;` instead of `position: absolute;`

Comment: ok I will try that but when I converted those % to px/rem, it is not overlapping. Thank you for reply.

Answer (score 0):

For this instead of using % use static unit like px to align them horizontally and vertically which will prevent them from resizing, also do not provide your margin in % put it in px.
`OR`
Here is the solution, well it will prevent distortion of your structure but spacing between left border window and your structure may vary . Well i did it for only two rectangles you should try for rest others. The ways is you can go with your code except one thing after giving left and top values in vh,vw or % for div1 , for the rest of dives give them left and top value relative to your div1 for which you can use

```
left:calc(div1_left_value + additional_value_in_px);
```

Similarly to top i.e.

```
top:calc(div1_top_value + additional_value_in_px)
```

Basically it statically place your all divs with respect to the position of 1st div.

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main_div{
    height:100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    
    
}

.div1{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20vh;
    left:15vw;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.div2{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background:red;
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(20vh + 100px);
    left:calc(15vw + 100px);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="nav.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main_div">
            <div class="div1"></div>
            <div class="div2"></div>
        </div>
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->
        
        <script src="" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```